# How can I get the right response from GCM to delete invalid registrationID's with php?

Tags: php, android, push, response, google-cloud-messaging

I hope someone can help me! Sorry for my English ;)
I have following PHP-Code:

```
    //Android - Push Notification Variables
    $apiKey = '';

    //Android - Push Notification Service

    $registrationIDs = array();

    $abfrage = "SELECT id, registrationId, active FROM `push-android` WHERE active = 'true'";
    $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage) or die(mysql_error());
    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
    {
        $id = $row->id;
        $registrationIDs[] = $row->registrationId;
    }
    $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';

    $fields = array(
                    'registration_ids'  => $registrationIDs,
                    'data'              => array( "message" => $message ),
                    );

    $headers = array( 
                        'Authorization: key='.$apiKey,
                        'Content-Type: application/json'
                    );

    // Open connection
    $ch = curl_init();

    // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

    // Execute post
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    // Close connection
    curl_close($ch);

    $obj = json_decode($result);
    $return = $obj->{'failure'};

    print_r($obj);
?>
```

So, what I can do, to get the right response from GCM to delete invalid registrationID's from my Database?
I have install the App on my Android Phone, send a notifiaction, what works fine.
After i deinstall the App, send a notification, and the response says:

> stdClass Object ( [multicast_id] => 8.6408433884968E+18 [success] => 1
>   [failure] => 0 [canonical_ids] => 0 [results] => Array ( [0] =>
>   stdClass Object ( [message_id] => 0:13813433954546524%df6f31cff9fd7ecd
>   ) ) )

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't get `InvalidRegistration` after un-installing the app. You would get `NotRegistered` error.

However, it takes time for the GCM server to identify that the app was un-installed from the device. That's why you get a successful response from GCM when you send a message immediatelly after un-installing the app. Try sending the message several times. For me, usually after the 2nd message I send to the device (after un-install) I get the `NotRegistered` error.

Comment: Ohh, thank you very much for the information. 

What can i do, do get the "right error" from the GCM server in the production mode?

And contains the "NotRegistered" error the invalid registrationID's?
i need it, do delete the ID's from the database!

Thank you very much.

Comment: @user2854393 I'm not sure I understood the comment. If you are asking how to get the "NotRegistered" error - I answered that - send a message to the registration ID who uninstalled the app multiple times. That response doesn't contain the invalid registration ID, since you already know that registration ID (if you send a JSON with more than one registration ID, then based on the position of the NotRegistered error in the response you'll know which registration ID should be deleted (if the 3rd message got this error, delete the 3rd registration ID that appeared in your request).

Comment: For Example, i send 10 Push Messages! And number 3 and number 6 cannot send, i get a NotRegistered error.
So, what can i do, to get the RegisteredID from message number 3 and number 6? I need it, to delete it from my database!
How i can program this?
Thank you very much!

Comment: I have 3 times, the same RegisteredID in the database.
And when i send the RegisteredID's to the GCM server, i get following response: stdClass Object ( [multicast_id] => 6.9559567529457E+18 [success] => 0 [failure] => 1 [canonical_ids] => 0 [results] => Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [error] => NotRegistered ) ) )
So, i need the 3 RegisteredID's, that i send to the GCM Server, to delete it from the database. Do you understand what i mean?
Thank you!

Comment: @user2854393 The response in your last comment only contains a single registration ID, which means your request contained a single registration ID, and that's the registration ID you need to delete. If you send 10 messages and get NotRegistered for the 3rd message, you should delete the 3rd registration ID that appeared in the registration_ids array of your JSON request.

Comment: can you give me pls an code-example?
on the top of this topic, there is my code! 
Thank you @user2854393